# How to add additional parameter like (rel="Y" data-behavior="X" data-token="XXX" class="XXX") with a hyper link created by using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a hyper link using java script. 
Here is code snippet

```js
var a = 1374.75;
var b = 'Hotel Delhi Airport Link';
var url = 'https://www.instamojo.com/stayuncle/payments-for-stayuncle'
var link = decodeURIComponent(url+'?data_amount='+a+'&data_Field_68092='+b)

alert("Redirecting to"+ link)
location.href = link
```

I want to pass following attribute with this link  like 
rel="X" data-behavior="Y"  data-token="Z" class="P"

As we usually pass these parameter with  hyper link using html tag  
 like

```
<p>
    <a href="https://www.instamojo.com/stayuncle/payments-for-stayuncle/"
                     rel="X" data-behavior="Y"  data-token="Z" class="P">check</a>
</p>
```

How can I do same in javascript?

Comment: `element.attributeName = 'value'`

Comment: When you set location.href, the element's attributes are not passed, even when that anchor is clicked on the those attributes are still not passed. Those attributes are used by some framework, like bootstrap, jquery, etc, to provide some functionality within that framework. For instance maybe allowing for a modal overlay.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes, what u were saying is correct .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't decode the data in the URL, you should encode it. Encode each value by itself:

```
var link = url +
  '?data_amount=' + encodeURIComponent(a) +
  '&data_Field_68092=' + encodeURIComponent(b);
```

Regarding the attributes in the link, they are not related to the URL at all. If you click on the link they won't be included in the request. They may have some other function for any code that catches the click event and does something different, but that is not repeatable by putting anything in an URL.